# Help with sorting MATRIX values in Super Search results

Tags: matrix, supersearch, sort, orderby

I'm using matrix extension to get the lowest value of a column in a search. The problem that I have is to sort results:

this is my code:

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="my_channel"}

    {my_matrix_field:lowest col="column_name"}

{/exp:super_search:results}
```

I tried using `orderby="column_name"` but it doesn't work

Many thanks in advance…

Comment: Do you mean you want to order the Super Search results by the value of your Matrix column?

Comment: I really want to order the Super Search results by the lowest value of the Matirx column.

Answer (score 1):

You can't order your Super Search results by a function of another fieldtype like that. But wehat you can do is write a custom extension and then use the [super_search_prep_order](http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/extension_hooks/#super_search_prep_order) extension hook.

> The Rating module uses this hook to sniff for an order directive like `order=rating`. When it sees that, it runs its own routine to order the list of known entry ID's by Bayesian rating. The Rating module returns a forced order list of entry ID's as part of the order directive that Super Search will later use against the DB. Another extension could behave similarly and force the order of entries as it sees fit.